# Is it possible to install a SVN plugin for Eclipse without getting a security warning?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install a Subversion plugin for Eclipse.  I have tried both Subclipse and Subversive using the update sites and they both end up with this nasty warning:

[image]

I know I can simply click 'OK' and continue, but I would much prefer to run code that comes from a trustworthy source and I know has not been tampered with.

Is there any way to install a SVN plugin for Eclipse without running unsigned code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the SVN plugins that is not signed so there is no way to avoid this warning.

Since Subversive comes from Eclipse most of the plugins should be signed. It should just be the 'connectors' which are not signed since they come from polarion.